# paper-ripple fires on touch rather than selected

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

On my cell phone, `paper-ripple` fires when I touch the element, rather than something is selected.

I've noticed this is also the same behavior [when using the element catalog paper ripple demo on my cell phone](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-ripple?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-ripple). However, this is not the same behavior on [the google design site which uses paper ripple but not polymer](https://design.google.com/).

For touch screens- How can I make the paper-ripple behavior like the google design site where the ripple only fires when something is selected rather than touched?

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{show}}">
  <section class="relative enabled-hover"
    data-name="portfolio"
    on-tap="jumpToPage">

    <div class="vertical layout">
      <div>
        <div>
          <h2 class="section-title">Portfolio</h2>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="layout horizontal center-center">
          <iron-icon class="big" icon="build"></iron-icon>
          <iron-icon class="big" icon="cloud-circle"></iron-icon>
          <iron-icon class="big" icon="http"></iron-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <paper-ripple
      fit
      id="ripple"
      initial-opacity="0.95"
      opacity-decay-velocity="0.98"
      hidden$="{{hideRipple}}">
    </paper-ripple>
```

Answer (score 1):

The ripple is meant to be visual feedback to the user on an interaction. The elements catalog demo shows the ripple when a selection is made on the menu items. If you want to turn the ripple off on buttons and fabs, I believe all support the `noink` attribute.

If you just want the icons to ripple, try https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-icon-button instead of iron-icon, and remove the paper-ripple.

Comment: I would like to emulate the ripple behavior from https://design.google.com/ where the ripple does not give visual feedback from a touch, but from a selection(tap).